# The requested URL /folder/controller/method was not found on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

I migrated my web-app onto aws server. When I type the domain name than it loads the login page of my web-app. After typing username and password and click the submit button it shows me this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /bitcoin_new/Login/login_check was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.techseed.co.in Port 80

Here is my .htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder_name/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

why do I get this error?

Comment: For test sake, would it work with `/bitcoin_new/index.php/Login/login_check`?

Comment: @Tpojka I check it but it doesnt work

Comment: Hm, maybe try with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]`.

Comment: Or `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` (notice question mark).

Comment: @Tpojka , No its not working

Comment: Hey Anyone is there.. Please help me to out these

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Why don't you try this?